# Bootstrap glyphicons not loading

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3

This question has been asked couple of times before, but I have never seen this situation I am in right now.

I am making a website using the `codeigniter` framework in combination with `bootstrap` as a front-end framework. Therefor, my project tree roughly looks like this

```
MyProject/
├── application/
├── system/
└── assets/
    └── bootstrap
        ├── css/
        │   └── bootstrap.min.css
        └── fonts/
            ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
            ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
            ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
            ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
            └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

The `bootstrap.min.css` includes these fonts using font-face, like so:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

    src: url('/assets/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
    src: url('/assets/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/assets/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), 
         url('/assets/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('/assets/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), 
         url('/assets/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

For some reason, the `css` just seems to skip that whole part, since the fonts not only do not work, they are also not shown in chrome's `developer tools` under the section network. It doesn't even show an error, it's not even in there.

How can I fix this?

**Edit 1**
I noticed the `src`'s `url` was incorrect, however it is just a minor mistake since this does not have anything to do with the fact that the errors don't show in chrome's `developer tools`

**Edit 2**
After loads of more trying, I noticed it didn't work in a very basic html either, being this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Hello</title>

        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>
        <p><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-search"></span> Hello</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then I started researching some more of this strange behaviour and stumbled across this link, where it is stated that in v4.0, glyphicons are removed from bootstrap. That is why I think the glyphicons are removed from bootstrap all together.

If you think I am wrong and see the mistake I am making, please do reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a minor mistake but isn't it supposed to be: glyphicon glyphicon-search

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Hello</title>

        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Hello</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Notice that you have added an extra 's' after glyphicon... It's not glyphicons, it's glyphicon...

Comment: I honestly don't know if I should thank you or not, because on 1 hand you did help me but you also made me feel like a dumb-ass. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I'll take the compliment! :D To err is human and some such... ;)

Answer (score 0):

How are you including the fonts in your HTML? You will need to place the  element to the fonts *before* the  element to bootstrap or whatever CSS you are using to include those fonts.

You can read more on Mozilla's [guide to using web fonts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Web_fonts). Look under the heading 'Using an online font service' (#5 specifically). While you're including the files yourself, the principle of properly including the files in the correct order.

edit: After looking back over it I think I've seen the issue. Looking at the src urls, it looks like the bootstrap CSS is expecting the the `fonts` folder to be in the `assets` directory, not the bootstrap directory. So you'll either need to move the `fonts` folder to the `assets` directory, or change the src urls in bootstrap to include the `assets/bootstrap/fonts/`.

Comment: Do you mean I have to include the `css` of bootstrap before the `css` of my own page?

Comment: @VellosFree I apologize, I just realized I answered incorrectly, but looking back over it I think I've seen the issue. Looking at the src urls, it looks like the bootstrap CSS is expecting the the `fonts` folder to be in the `assets` directory, not the `bootstrap` directory. So you'll either need to move the font folder to the assets directory, or change the src urls in bootstrap to include the `assets/bootstrap/fonts/`.

Comment: That is a minor mistake I discovered yes, but that still does bit solve the issue. The problem is that inside chrome's `developer tools` no error is shown regarding a wrong url, which it does show if I were to make a mistake in a image url.